# Where in my .phtml file do I tell it to 'use' the layout.phtml file I made?

Tags: php, zend-framework, layout

I'm kind of lost.

I made a sort of 'master page' that I want a page to use. Where do I declare it?

**MainLayout.phtml**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
        <div>
            <ul>        
                <li><a href="#">Navigation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Navigation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Navigation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Navigation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Navigation</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Index.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->doctype() ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <?php echo $this->headMeta() ?>
        <meta name="language" content="en" />
        <title><?php echo $this->escape($this->title) ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is the first page I made.</h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using the Zend framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, what Pascal said is correct: when `Zend_Layout` is used, it will insert the content of the view script into the master layout where

```
echo $this->layout()->content;
```

is called. Since it is an insertion, you do not include the entire HTML page though. In your example, the template and the layout both contain a full page with HTML, HEAD and BODY elements, resulting in invalid markup.

However, since View Scripts are processed before Layout scripts, you can set the layout from the View script through the [layout helper](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_View/Helper/Zend_View_Helper_Layout.html), using

```
$this->layout()->setLayout('foo');
```

You can also set the layout from the Controller

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
```

And of course, like everything else in ZF, it is configurable from the application.ini as well. The [`Zend_Layout` Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.quickstart.html) is really best start to learn about this component.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say in any of those files that `index.phtml` should be embedded in `layout.phtml` : the `Zend_Layout` component will do that for you :

- The content will be generated by the page *(using index.phtml)*
- And it will be injected into the `content` property of the layout *(The name of that property is configurable, of course)*

But all this has to be configured -- generally from your Bootstrap file, or using some configuration file.

For more informations and detailed explanations and examples, you might want to take a look at :

- [Zend Framework's QuickStart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.html)

  - And, more specifically, the chapter [Create A Layout](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-layout.html)
- Or the e-book [Zend Framework: Surviving The Deep End](http://survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0)

  - And, more specifically, [Chapter 10. Setting The Design With Zend_View, Zend_Layout, HTML 5 and Yahoo! User Interface Library](http://survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/setting.the.design.with.zend.view.zend.layout.html.5.and.yahoo.user.interface.library)